# Change the blocks color on hover and on click (and stay active)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following Code:

How can I edit my CSS in such a way so .pricing-customer background would change to one `color:#333` and all of my paragraph styles would change to another `color:#fff` when I hover the `.pricing-customer` block. Because now I if I hover the block it change only the background and the paragraph style only changes when I hover the paragraph itself. And how can I make the color of `.pricing-customer` and all my paragraph would change on click? (To the same color as on hover)

```css
.pricing-customer {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}
p.pricing-number {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fead0d;
}
p.pricing-monthes {
  color: #5e6977;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
}
p.emails {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use pseudo selector `:hover`

```js
$('.pricing-customer').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.pricing-customer {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}
p.pricing-number {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fead0d;
}
p.pricing-monthes {
  color: #5e6977;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
}
p.emails {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.pricing-customer:hover, .pricing-customer.active {

 background-color: #333;
}
.pricing-customer:hover p , .pricing-customer p.active{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. Please, read the question a bit more attentively. "Because now I if I hover the block it change only the background and the paragraph style only changes when I hover the paragraph itself. And how can I make the color of .pricing-customer and all my paragraph would change on click? (To the same color as on hover)"

Comment: @Morgari ive edited my answer. check it out. i use jquery for the click function and alter the css.

Comment: @ron-basco Wow works great for me! Just one question - how can I remove active with second click? Thank you in advance

Comment: ive edited it again. i used `toggleClass` for adding/removing class on click.

Comment: please accept my answer as correct if it suits your needs.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you will need to add a small code snippet which will toggle `active` class on `pricing-customer` div element.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .pricing-customer {
        background: #fff;
        min-height: 250px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
      }
      p.pricing-number {
        font-size: 52px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: #fead0d;
      }
      p.pricing-monthes {
        color: #5e6977;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 21px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
      }
      p.emails {
        color: #444;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 21px;
      }
      .pricing-customer:hover {
        background-color: #333;
      }
      .pricing-customer:hover p {
        color: #fff;
      }
      .pricing-customer.active,
      .pricing-customer.active p {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
      <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
      <br>
      <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
      <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      $('.pricing-customer').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, read the question a bit more attentively."Because now I if I hover the block it change only the background and the paragraph style only changes when I hover the paragraph itself. And how can I make the color of .pricing-customer and all my paragraph would change on click? (To the same color as on hover)"

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pricing-customer {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}
.pricing-customer:hover{
  background: #333;
}
p.pricing-number:hover,p.pricing-monthes:hover,p.pricing-emails:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
p.pricing-number {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fead0d;
}
p.pricing-monthes {
  color: #5e6977;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
}
p.emails {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```css
html:active {
  background: yellow;   
}
```

```html
<h2>click anywhere</h2>
```